# Using MVC 3 to dynamically create Site.css on IIS 6. Works in dev, prod fails. Why?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis-6

I am using an MVC controller/action to dynamically create the site.css in my MVC 3 site.  The way it works is I map a route to Site.css like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("CSS", "Content/Site.css", new { controller = "CSS", action = "Index" });
```

Then in my CSSController I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    string path = Request.PhysicalPath.Replace("Site.css","SiteStyles.css");
    byte[] data = null;

    try {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            data = ProcessCSS(fs);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.Write(new LogEntry(e.Message, "Error", 99, 1001, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error, "CSS Error", null));
        throw e;
    }

    return File(data, "text/css","Site.css");
}
```

What's going on in the ProcessCSS method is it's going through SiteStyles.css and performing a find/replace on some constants I have defined, so that I can have a set of colors defined at the top as named constants, then anywhere I need that color in the site I just use the named constant.  That way I can change the color once, and it propagates to all of the appropriate places in the stylesheet without me having to go touch 5-6 different places.

The above code works great debugging in my local environment and on the dev server, which is Windows Server 2003 running IIS6.  However, when I deploy it to a production server that is also Windows Server 2003 running IIS6 the css is not being loaded and when I try to browse to Site.css (which should be getting mapped via my route) I get a 404 not found error.  If I go to my dev server and get the output for Site.css and create a physical Site.css file on the production server, it works.

Any idea why this is failing on the production server?

I added some logging to my CSSControler to log where it is looking for SiteStyles.css and the log simply isn't being generated on the production server, which tells me the server is ignoring the mapped route entirely and not executing the code in the Controller.

Any suggestions on where to start are appreciated.

Comment: When on development, are you using the built-in Visual Studio web server?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should double-check your IIS configuration on the production server to make sure that the necessary mappings are applied.

Are you using a wildcard (star) mapping in IIS on your development server, or did you define a mapping for the .css extension?  You may need to verify that the production server has the same mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add write rights to the folder your css is located in to the user that your pool is run under.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I know this may be misplaced but my rep is not sufficient to comment so I thought this may help too